# jQuery input mask

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want the `onBlur` event of the input box to trigger the `CheckMask()` validation function to see whether the data entered by the user is correct or not. The data format is `abc 123`. If the input isn't in the correct format, I want to display an error message.

Can someone help me modify this code? I'm not getting the correct result.

```
function CheckMask() {
    var value = $('.Mask-tttnnn').val();
    if (value.length <= 3) {
        char = value.substring(value.length - 1);
        if (!(isNaN(char))) {
            var newval = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
            $(Mask - tttnnn).val(newval);
        }
    }
    if (value.length > 3) {
        char = value.substring(value.length - 1);
        if (isNaN(char)) {
            var newval = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
            $(Mask - tttnnn).val(newval);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="checkval" value="" type="text" class="Mask-tttnnn" onBlur="CheckMask()" />
```

Comment: _What do you mean_ by "not getting the correct result"? I can assume you mean your function is letting through incorrect data, but you should be telling that to me, not the other way round.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that is raising an error. Just doing checks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery input mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952262/jquery-input-mask). You've asked this question before, which has more than adequate answers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: remove the onBlur from your HTML. Keep code and mark-up separate.

Step 2: construct a regular expression you would like to validate. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

```
[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}
```

Step 3: attach a function to the blur event of your input using jQuery

```
$('checkval').blur(function () {
    // check $(this).val() against the regex
    // alert if it fails or whatever you want to do
});
```

Comment: i want to call the function on Class intead of textbox id plus also want to call from textbox like i did already

Comment: @meer Do some research! Changing the selector is possibly the easiest thing to do in jQuery. We're not here to write everything for you.