# How can I append a leading 0 in MVC 4 DateTime in an EditorFor HTMLHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I'm running into an issue in my MVC 4 application when using an input mask in my edit view for a DateTime. The input mask that I'm using forces an input to be formatted like: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm". This works great until an edit it attempted.

An input of "09/11/2013 07:00" ends up looking like "91/12/0137 30:00" in my EditorFor helper.

**How can I force a "0" to append to a month and hour less than two digits?**

Here is my property:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Begin Leave")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BeginLeave { get; set; }
```

This is my HtmlHelper EditorFor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeginLeave)
```

Here is where the input mask sets the format:

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#BeginLeave").mask("99/99/9999 99:99");
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: what does "input mask" mean exactly ?

Comment: It's jquery. Here's an example of how it is used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952262/jquery-input-mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by adding an EditorTemplate for DateTime.

This was done by adding a PartialView to the Shared/EditorTemplates folder named "System.DateTime", and the code for the EditorTemplate is:

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : Model.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm"))
```

This returns the output as I needed it.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue using the jquery input mask, where when populating a datetime value it would drop the leading zeros. Here's my solution:

The ViewModel:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[Display(Name = "Begin Leave")]
public DateTime BeginLeave { get; set; }
```

The View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeginLeave, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}")
```

NOTE: This also will work for @Html.TextBoxFor()

Answer (score 1):

You should add an attribute to the property, like this :

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTimeOffset PublishedOn { get; set; }
```

Pay close attention to the Attribute options `ApplyFormatInEditMode` and `DataFormatString`.

Also check what data you are sending back to the server, there might be something wrong in the input you are sending ( for example something not serializing properly? )

Comment: This did not change the format. The view is still recieving the datetime in the format of "9/10/2013 7:30:00 AM", which is displayed as "91/12/0137 30:00" when added to the textbox with input mask and displayed as "9/10/2013 7:30:00 AM" without the input mask. I need to get "09/10/2013 07:30" back to my view if possible.